# How can you add threading support to CodeBlock's compiler?

Tags: compiler-errors, g++

I'm on Ubuntu 20.04 and with g++, I can compile a code with pthreads in it using 'g++ -o file file.cpp -lpthread'. However, I can't do this using CodeBlocks, because it gives me an 'undefined reference to pthread_create' error. How can I integrate the pthread support to CodeBlock's compiler, so that it supports pthreads?

Comment: Use preferably `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g file.cpp -lpthread -o prog` and read documentation of [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) and of [Code::Blocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/) -which can be configured to run that GCC command and is *not* a compiler

Comment: For your next question please provide some [mre] with some C++ code